# How to print a PDF in Landscape mode with Powershell and Ghostscript?

Tags: powershell, ghostscript

I'm trying to print a group of files located on the server with portrait or landscape orientation. However, I've been unable to have GhostScript print the file in landscape via Powershell.

Here are 3 attempt, where I've no success.
C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.27\bin\gswin64c.exe -dPrinted -dDuplex -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOSAFER -dNumCopies=1 -dORIENT1=false -sDEVICE=mswinpr2 -sOutputFile="\Spool$printer" "$Filepath$Document"

C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.27\bin\gswin64c.exe -dPrinted -dDuplex -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOSAFER -dNumCopies=1 -dORIENT1=true -sDEVICE=mswinpr2 -sOutputFile="\Spool$printer" "$Filepath$Document"

-- This following example allowed me to manually select landscape orientation via dialog, but it still printed in portrait mode.
C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.27\bin\gswin64c.exe -dPrinted -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOSAFER -dNumCopies=1 -sDEVICE=mswinpr2 -c "<</Orientation 3>> setpagedevice" -dAutoRotatePages=/None -sOutputFile="\Spool$printer" "$Filepath$Document"

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The mswinpr2 device (not Ghostscript per se) will render the content to the media defined by the printer driver. As far as I know (and I have not checked), the device does not perform any kind of scaling or rotation, whatever media size the input file has is printed to the media, if the input is landscape and the media is portrait then part of the content will fall off the media. You can try setting a fixed media (-dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=..., -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=...)size to Ghostscript, and use -dFitPage which will fit the content to the media. That should rotate the content if required.

Comment: As a side note, AutoRotatePages only works with the pdfwrite device, you should update to a newer version of Ghostscript; 9.27 is 4 years old and has a number of security vulnerabilities. Though using -dNOSAFER removes almost all protection anyway, you shouldn't do that either.